# PHP Google Drive API creates empty XML file

Tags: php, xml, google-drive-api

I'm struggling with a [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), I'm trying to send to google drive specified folder my data.xml and with this code it works perfectly. But the created file on google drive is always empty /0 bytes/.

```
    <?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../html/my-key.json');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']);
    $client->setSubject('my-service@account.com');

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $data = file_get_contents("data.xml");

    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
        array('name' => 'data',
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => 'text/xml',
            'parents' => array('myFolderID'),
            'uploadType' => 'media'));

    $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));
```

My data.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <data>
        <item>
            <id>2546485</id>
            <c>0</c>
            <p>0,00</p>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2546809</id>
            <c>0</c>
            <p>0,00</p>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>10982762</id>
            <c>30</c>
            <p>4,26</p>
        </item>
    </data>
```

I've tried changing mimeTypes and uploadTypes with no luck so far. *File_get_contents* returns .xml data correctly.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to upload a XML file to the specific folder in Google Drive using Drive API v3.
- You want to achieve this using php.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

Please modify `$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array())` and `$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array())` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
  'name' => 'data',
  'parents' => array('myFolderID'),
));

$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
  'data' => $data,
  'mimeType' => 'text/xml',
  'uploadType' => 'media',
  'fields' => 'id',
));
```

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already been able to upload a file to Google Drive using Drive API.
- I think that in your case, `uploadType` can also use `multipart`.

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Upload files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: That was it, moving _parents_ from _create_ method helped, thanks!

Comment: @Doseq Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.